# spl_autoload_register with non static class method as autoloader function?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use spl_autoload_register to use an instantiated object as the autoloader. Is it possible? I have seen in a couple of places where people have used a classes static function as the autoloader, but not an object.

Example:

```
class loadFile{
    function loadObject($object){
    //load object here
    }
}
$loadmefiles = new loadFile();
//use $loadmefiles->loadObject() as autoloader
spl_autoload_register();
$goat = new Animal('goat');
```

Hopefully you understand what I am getting at.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is done by passing an array to [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register): the first element being the object, the second being the name of the method as a string:

```
spl_autoload_register(array($loadmefiles, 'loadObject'));
```

From the [callable documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it static as an alternative.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
    Pi_loader::autoload($class);
});
```

If not...

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
    $loader = new Pi_loader();
    $loader->autoload($class);
});
```